# Problem querying GraphQL with Gatsby-Apollo-Postgres setup: "Network error: failed to fetch" [apollo]

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, react-apollo

I'm using Gatsby, Apollo, and a local Postgres server. I want to connect Apollo to my local postgres db to serve data to Gatsby dynamically via GraphQL queries.

I'm getting the error `$Network error: Failed to fetch` when I load my Gatsby page.

I followed the Gatsby-Apollo example template [here](https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo). I'm using a `postgres address` in the `uri` section of the ApolloClient setup:

```js
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'postgres://MY_USER@localhost:5432/MY_DB', // I think this part is wrong
  fetch,
  fetchOptions: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  },
});
```

In chrome console the error says:
`URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`

Which makes me think I need an "http" format for the postgres address. What am I missing? Do I need to create my own Apollo server using nodejs, connect it to postgres, then set *that* server address in the `uri` parameter above?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to fetch from a PostgreSQL endpoint. You should put there a GraphQL endpoint such as Apollo Server.